# A subspace $A$ of $X$ is $C^*$-embedded in $X$ iff every pair of completely separated sets in $A$ is completely separated in $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Show that a subspace $A$ of $X$ is $C^*$-embedded in $X$ iff every pair of completely
separated sets in $A$ is completely separated in $X$.

This is problem 15E from Willard's 'General Topology'. The 'only if' part is easy, but I don't know how to do the 'if' part.

Comment: See theorem 1.17 of L. Gillman & M. Jerison: *Rings of Continuous Functions*.

Comment: I'm aware of that book, but I don't have it nor is there a free copy of it.

Comment: @Brett Lane: See [here](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b4407145&view=1up&seq=7)

Comment: @Ulli Thanks for the link, that answers my question.